# Extend a Model from a Rails Engine (not replace it)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-engines

I have a Rails app that uses a gem called ActsAsTaggableOnSteroids, which is a Rails Engine. Specifically, I'm using [PavelNartov's fork](https://github.com/PavelNartov/acts_as_taggable_on_steroids) of the gem. But nevermind that.

I need to add specific functionality to the `Tag` model, which is supplied by the engine.

But, according to my understanding of Rails engines and the magical loading functionality in Rails, if I put a file called "tag.rb" in my models directory, then it will completely *replace* the one from the Engine.

Ideally, I would be able to do something like:

```
class Tag < ActsAsTaggable::Tag
  # my stuff
end
```

...but alas, that doesn't work because the model supplied by the engine is not namespaced.

So, I came up with this nightmare, which I put in `app/models/tag.rb`:

```
path = ActsAsTaggable::Engine.config.eager_load_paths.grep(/models/).first
require File.join(path, 'tag')
Tag.class_eval { include TagConcern }
```

But there has to be a better way! I feel like I'm missing something. I'd prefer not to add this strangeness to my app if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just require the file by looking up the path of the gem's model:

```
require File.join(Gem::Specification.find_by_name("bborn-acts_as_taggable_on_steroids").gem_dir, 'app/models/tag')

Tag.class_eval do
  # ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks! That's certainly an improvement over what I wrote. I'll wait another day or so to see if there is a better, more Rails-y way of doing this sort of inheritance before using your answer.

Comment: The require statement here is what ensures you don't clobber the gem's version. You can inherit from it or use class_eval or re-open it as you see fit.